# Azure Function - Call function from another function

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have one function created in .net core and i face some problem in send mail. 
I am thinking to create another function in .net framework that send mail.

I need a solution that will do following,
.net core function will get data and that call .net framework function to send mail. Is this technically possible?

Comment: Yes. You can trigger Functions in different ways. So you could, for instance, put a message on a queue or call an Http triggered function. As is, this post is no fit for SO. Please refer to [ask].

Comment: Both functions have different framework so solutions are different. Can you give me some blog reference.

Comment: If you trigger a function, you don't care about which technology it is written in, right? Just define a contract between caller and callee, the rest is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

In ideal scenario try adding a class library for all your E-mail or messaging need  as per right design pattern and call the library from your azure function.

Since we are moving toward cloud design pattern , it makes perfect sense to utilize sendgrid for these kind of functionality.

Though if you are still planning to use SMTP server to achieve it, i would suggest you to write your implementation like below:

1. Create class library which compile and create your email message and store it in queue, which you will call it from azure function 1
2. You can create function 2 which will be queue trigger , and with thah message coming in you can actually send it to intended recipient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Function V1 output Sendgrid bindings to send mail. Check the below article for examples and guidance on how to achieve this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid?tabs=csharp

SMTP is not allowed on Azure to remove the risk of anyone misusing(ex. SPAM) the outbound IPs that is shared across multiple clients.

Please read more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity